# Repeating data when looping through array using geofire and firebase

Tags: angularjs, loops, firebase, q, geofire

Please take a look at my code.

```
  var posts = PostsData.getPosts();   
  var postFunc = function(key) {
      return posts[key];  
  }

  $scope.$watch($scope.active, function() {
      $timeout(function() {
    var markers = [];

    for (var key in posts) {

          console.log(key);
          var p = gf.get(key).then(function(location) { 
          var post = postFunc(key);
          console.log(key);
          return ({
            idKey: key,
            title: post.title,
            coords: {
              latitude: location[0],
              longitude: location[1]
            }
           });
      });
      markers.push(p);

    }

    $q.all(markers).then(function(markers) {
    $scope.markers = markers;
    });

  });
})
```

}

Within the loop there are two lines of "console.log(key)".
The first console.log prints an accurate representation of the data which is unique keys. The second console.log prints repeating identical data, which is inaccurate. I'm having trouble understanding why this is happening.

Thanks so much for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is quite normal that from second `console.log(key)` onward you have same value. The reason for that is your async function `gf.get(key).then(function(location) { .. }`. By the time this function is called your loop has finished execution and the value of **`key` is the last value from your loop**. I am not sure what `gf.get` do but if `posts` is an array you can achieve your result with help of recursion as shown below

```
var posts = PostsData.getPosts();   
var postFunc = function(key) {
    return posts[key];  
}

var markers = [];
var getMarkers(key) {

    if (key > posts.length - 1) {

        // promise resolved for each item in posts
        $q.all(markers).then(function(markers) {
            $scope.markers = markers;
        }

        return;
    }

    console.log(key);
    gf.get(key).then(function(location) {
        var post = postFunc(key);
        console.log(key);
        markers.push({
            idKey: key,
            title: post.title,
            coords: {
                latitude: location[0],
                longitude: location[1]
            }
        });

        getMarkers(++key);
    });
}

$scope.$watch($scope.active, function() {
    markers = [];
    getMarkers(0);
});
```

**Note:** In this approach we wait for each promise to be resolved before moving to next call of `gf.get`

Comment: Thank you so much! I had to make some slight changes but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Another technique to fix the problem is to use an IIFE closure.

```
var markers = [];

for (var key in posts) {
    //IIFE closure
    (function (key) {
        console.log(key);
        var p = gf.get(key).then(function(location) { 
            var post = postFunc(key);
            console.log(key);
            return ({
                idKey: key,
                title: post.title,
                coords: {
                    latitude: location[0],
                    longitude: location[1]
                }
            });
        });
        markers.push(p);
    })(key);
}
```

By using an IIFE ([Immediately Invoked Function Expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression)) the value of each `key` is preserved until the function inside the `.then` method completes.